# How to set maxFileSize for FileUploadFactory when using Joy?

Tags: jodd

Can someone please let me know how to configure the maxFileSize for fileUploads in Jodd, when using Joy?

I've tried in joy.props, even under [joy.madvoc] section with the earlier working:

```
madvocConfig.fileUploadFactory.maxFileSize=-1
```

But have no luck :(

Another question is how to force it, to report error, as without it, got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.mycircle.action.CircleAction.add(CircleAction.java:78)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
jodd.madvoc.ActionRequest.invokeActionMethod(ActionRequest.java:256)
jodd.madvoc.ActionRequest.lambda$createExecutionArray$1(ActionRequest.java:226)
jodd.madvoc.ActionRequest.invoke(ActionRequest.java:240)
jodd.madvoc.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:79)
jodd.madvoc.interceptor.ActionInterceptor.apply(ActionInterceptor.java:38)
jodd.madvoc.ActionRequest.invoke(ActionRequest.java:240)
jodd.joy.i18n.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:46)
jodd.madvoc.interceptor.ActionInterceptor.apply(ActionInterceptor.java:38)
jodd.madvoc.ActionRequest.invoke(ActionRequest.java:240)
jodd.madvoc.ActionRequest.lambda$createExecutionArray$0(ActionRequest.java:209)
jodd.madvoc.ActionRequest.invoke(ActionRequest.java:240)
jodd.madvoc.component.MadvocController.invoke(MadvocController.java:163)
jodd.madvoc.MadvocServletFilter.doFilter(MadvocServletFilter.java:109)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
jodd.decora.DecoraServletFilter.doFilter(DecoraServletFilter.java:144)
```

After debugging, I figured out that is due to file size limitation 100240 bytes defined in FileUploadFactory and AdaptiveFileUploadFactory as well.

I have a @In FileUpload image; in CircleAction and it become null due to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do so:

1. from `Joy` get to the `Madvoc`
2. in `Madvoc` get the `FileUploader` component - it's a new one that simply holds a `FileUploadFactory` instance.
3. Use it:)

Something like this:

```
public class MyWebApplication extends JoyContextListener {

    @Override
    protected JoddJoy createJoy() {
        final JoddJoy joy = super.createJoy();
        joy.withWebApp(webApp -> {
            webApp.withRegisteredComponent(FileUploader.class, fileUploader -> {
                AdaptiveFileUploadFactory adaptiveFileUploadFactory =
                    (AdaptiveFileUploadFactory) fileUploader.get();
                adaptiveFileUploadFactory.setMaxFileSize(10000000);
            });
        });
        return joy;
    }

}
```

The seccond way is to use `registerComponent` and simply pass your implementation of `FileUploader`.

Atm, it is not possible to set this value from the madvoc config, but I will fix that soon. There is no more `madvocConfig` - instead you can set each component. So you will be able to do so like this: `fileUploader.maxFileSize` (after the fix:).

Comment: Thanks Igor, you made my day! Now it works perfectly.